# Formatting in netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

I want to know how can I configure my netbeans ide to format my code in my specific need.
I need all my assignment in same line to easily distinguish it.
for eg:

```
 $a    = 1;
 $b    = 1;
 $c    = 1;
 $a++;
 some code

 $d    = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample code, I'm assuming that you want to do this for PHP. If so, then you can do it as follows:

- Select **Tools > Options > Editor**, then click the **Formatting** tab.
- Select **PHP** from the **Language** drop list, then **Alignment** from the **Category** drop list.
- A code sample will be displayed in the **Preview** window on the right side of the screen which includes some variable assignments near the end of the code:

  [image: withoutAlignment]
- Under **Group Multiline Alignment** check the **Assignment** box. Note that the assignment operators (`=`) in the code preview are now aligned:

  [image: withAlignment]

Notes:

- The column position used for aligning the assignment operators is dynamic, based on the length of the longest variable name. I don't think it is possible to place the assignment operator in a specific column as suggested by your code example.
- This approach is specific to PHP, and can't be used for formatting code in other languages such as Java or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting in NetBeans can be configured under "`Tools / Options / Editor / Formatting`", but I don't think that you can configure NetBeans to use your desired format.